# Is a used AT835b worth it?

Tags: microphone, shotgun

I might have a chance to buy a used AT835b shotgun mic at roughly 120USD or so. Its just the mic and the clip, no foam windscreen or anything else. Probably a quite few years old considering that its already discontinued.

Does anyone have any experience with one? I'll be using it with my H4N. I'm looking to get a shotgun microphone for better ambience rejection and for recording some sounds that I can't put the H4N too close to. Not for heavy use at the moment, just need to have a more directional microphone as I stay in the city. Too much ambient noise when recording sounds outdoors.

I know that the NTG-2 and ME66 are the recommended mics, but this isn't something that I use everyday at the moment so I'm a little concerned about the ROI on a more expensive shotgun microphone. I forsee the cost of a zeppelin and dead cat being a fair amount of investment too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have three and they all work well, we use them with Rycote softies.  All of them have been reliable, and not too noisy, especially considering their age and regular use.  For $120 I think the mic is definitely worth it, especially as it can be powered by a AA battery, in case you need to minimise the battery drain on the H4N.

Comment: Thanks Iain. Do you use them with the H4N too? Do you know how it compares to the H4N onboard mics or the NTG-2? I'm concern about how much ambience rejection can I get with the AT835b vs the onboards vs NTG-2.

Comment: We use them with Marantz PMD660 and PMD661s.  You will definitely have improved side rejection over the onboard mics, and I think that it should be similar if to the NTG-2.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look if I can find a similar deal on a NTG-2 since I'm concerned about the age of the mic. But sounds like a good thing to try out.